# Multiple DELETE in mysql not working with alias

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I used this scheme for a multiple DELETE

```
DELETE Table1, Table2, Table3
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON (Table2.ConditionID = Table1.ConditionID)
JOIN   Table3 ON (Table3.ConditionID = Table2.ConditionID)
WHERE  Table1.ConditionID = ?;
```

Why can't I use aliasnames like this

```
DELETE Table1, Table2, Table3
FROM   Table1 t1
JOIN   Table2 t2 ON (t2.ConditionID = t1.ConditionID)
JOIN   Table3 t3 ON (t3.ConditionID = t2.ConditionID)
WHERE  t1.ConditionID = ?;
```

I only get a normal Syntaxerror.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can, you just need to use the `ALIAS` name given after the `DELETE` keyword.

```
DELETE  t1, t2, t3
FROM    Table1 t1
        JOIN   Table2 t2 ON (t2.ConditionID = t1.ConditionID)
        JOIN   Table3 t3 ON (t3.ConditionID = t2.ConditionID)
WHERE   t1.ConditionID = ?;
```

Comment: OMG, sometimes it's better to stay in bed. Many thanks, now it works.